# print curl request in one line in Spring

Tags: java, spring

I want to be able to generate/log the curl of my requests in one line and print it in the console. Is there a lib for it? 
For example, if I call a GET from localhost:8080/example:

```
curl -X GET \
  http://localhost:8080/example \
  -H 'Accept: */*' \
  -H 'Cache-Control: no-cache' \
  -H 'Connection: keep-alive' \
  -H 'Postman-Token: 6c986d90-a4fd-4d98-aaea-48669a82d5c5,085e1d9d-5e76-4b5c-8858-75b975c88bf7' \
  -H 'User-Agent: PostmanRuntime/7.13.0' \
```

Comment: Is the question. When I hit the url on the application it should log the request?

Comment: @SubirKumarSao My web services requests should log their curl